# Count age in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date-arithmetic

Hi i want to count my age in jquery. Something like this-

Counting my age since, 18 years, 4 months, 2 weeks, 6 days, 5 hours, 17 minutes and 8 seconds

The second counter should be running. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery might be inappropriate. Try moment.js you can do crazy date manipulation with it easily. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Comment: here's an example http://codepen.io/madevelopers/pen/rdneA

Answer (score 1):

it is possible! do a function which checks the difference between your birthday and now. 
let it run every second

to let it run every second use setTimeout

[timing events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)